# how do i write test cases for jsonparser, jsonmapping and io exception using mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

i want to mock this service in controller, so that i can test this. how do i mock coreservice.getRelatedInfo to throw the given exceptions to test them.
i am trying to throw them but, i'm getting error. when i am testing for runtime exception it is working.

```
@PostMapping("/realtedcustomerinfo")
public ResponseEntity<List<CustomerInfoDTO>> 
getRelatedCustomerInfo(@RequestBody RelatedCustomerInfo 
relatedCustomerInfo) {
    log.info("Start of getRelatedCustomerInfo() input {}", 
 relatedCustomerInfo);
    List<CustomerInfoDTO> customerInfoDTOs = null;

    try {
        customerInfoDTOs = 
 coreService.getRelatedCustomerInfo(relatedCustomerInfo);
    } catch (JsonParseException e) {
        log.error("Exception details", e);
    } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
        log.error("Exception details", e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error("Exception details", e);
    }

    if (null == customerInfoDTOs) {
        log.info("End of getRelatedCustomerInfo() return {}", customerInfoDTOs);
        return new ResponseEntity<List<CustomerInfoDTO>>(new ArrayList<CustomerInfoDTO>(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    log.info("End of getRelatedCustomerInfo() return {}", customerInfoDTOs);
    return new ResponseEntity<List<CustomerInfoDTO>>(customerInfoDTOs, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Comment: can you show also the unit test which is failing?

Comment: We need more context. It is really not clear what you are asking for. You say you want to mock the service, so you can test it?! You either mock something OR you test it. So you basically want to mock the `coreService` object, but your code doesn't tell us where that is coming from.